# Confusion about joint probability distribution in Bayesian Inference setup

Tags: probability, bayesian, joint-distribution

I am confused by a simple fact but I can't solve my head around it!

It's known that:
$P(y,\theta) = P(y|\theta)*P(\theta)$
and
$P(y,\theta) = P(\theta|y)*P(y)$

Giving us: $P(\theta|y)*P(y) = P(y|\theta)*P(\theta)$ (both valid probability density functions)

But in bayesian inference literature we learn that $P(y|\theta)*P(\theta)$ is not a probability density function because $P(y|\theta)*P(\theta)$ when $P(y|\theta)$ as a likelihood does not sum to 1, needing the $P(y)$ as a denominator to normalize it and give a valid posterior probability density function.

So, my confusion is: is the joint density function **NOT** a joint **PROBABILITY** density function in $P(y,\theta) = P(y|\theta)*P(\theta)$ since the right hand side does not sum to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|y)\,p(y)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta) 
\end{equation}
are valid ***joint*** probability distributions for $(y,\theta)$. Both distributions integrate to 1 with respect to $y$ and $\theta$:
\begin{equation}
\iint p(\theta|y)\,p(y)\,dy\,d\theta = 1
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\iint p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta) \,dy\,d\theta = 1 . 
\end{equation}

But $p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)$ is not (in general) a valid ***conditional*** distribution for $\theta$ because it does not (necessarily) integrate to 1 with respect to $\theta$:
\begin{equation}
\int p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)\,d\theta = p(y) ,
\end{equation}
where $p(y)$ does not necessarily equal 1.

### Addendum

I'm addressing a question in a comment by the OP.

The marginal distribution for $y$ is computed from the joint distribution by integrating out $\theta$:
\begin{equation}
p(y) = \int p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)\,d\theta .
\end{equation}
For fixed $y$, $p(y)$ is a number, the density at $y$. But the density $p(y)$ is allowed to vary as we vary $y$. In
\begin{equation}
\int p(y)\,dy = 1
\end{equation}
$p(y)$ varies as $y$ varies so as to guarantee the result.

In the conditional distribution
\begin{equation}
p(\theta|y) = \frac{p(y|\theta)\,p(\theta)}{p(y)} ,
\end{equation}
we are holding $y$ fixed and so $p(y)$ is a number. If we chose to fix $y$ at a different value, then we get a different distribution for $\theta$ and a different value for $p(y)$.

(This can be a bit tricky at first and it's good to nail it down before proceeding.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! It totally makes sense now!
If it's ok, I'd like to add a very beginner's follow up question. (very embarrassing question)

Since () in ∫(|)()=() is a constant (not necessarily equal to 1), if we solve the ∬(|)() in parts, first in respect to , we will end with ∫() and this do not integrate to 1 since it's a constant. But ∬(|)() = 1. Where is the flaw in my thinking??

Comment: Got it!!! Thank you so much again for all the answers! I have researched and thought about it for days before asking it here. Everything now connects for me!

Comment: Glad to hear it.